# CARTO not styling 36 total representatives

Tags: carto, style, cartocss, css

I'm extremely new to CARTO and I'm still learning the ropes. I currently have this territory map where the colors represent a representative in a county.

[image: Territory map]

However, it isn't shading the 36 total representatives. It only shades 10 then groups the other 26 in `Others`.

This is my current layer style setup in Builder:

[image]

All I want to be able to do is a have a color for every representative and not have the `Others` category. I read that I may have to do something with CartoCSS, but it didn't guide me in the right direction.

What's the best way to go about this? If there's a better way for me to visualize what I'm trying to accomplish, please tell me.

I'm running CARTO self-hosted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. In order to style all your categories using CARTO Builder, you need to switch from values to CartoCSS as shown in the following gif:

[image: value-to-cartocss]

Secondly, you need to update the code [using basic CartoCSS conditionals](https://carto.com/help/building-maps/basic-cartocss-for-map-styling/). Notice that you would need to know the category names and colors in advance. You can use a code like this one.

```
#layer {
  polygon-fill: #666666;
  [ name = "Afghanistan" ] {
    polygon-fill: #5F4690;
  }
  [ name = "Åland Islands" ] {
    polygon-fill: #1D6996;
  }
  [ name = "Albania" ] {
    polygon-fill: #38A6A5;
  }
  [ name = "Algeria" ] {
    polygon-fill: #0F8554;
  }
  [ name = "American Samoa" ] {
    polygon-fill: #73AF48;
  }
  [ name = "Andorra" ] {
    polygon-fill: #EDAD08;
  }
  [ name = "Angola" ] {
    polygon-fill: #E17C05;
  }
  [ name = "Anguilla" ] {
    polygon-fill: #CC503E;
  }
  [ name = "Antarctica" ] {
    polygon-fill: #94346E;
  }
  [ name = "Antigua and Barbuda" ] {
    polygon-fill: #6F4070;
  }
}
#layer::outline {
  line-width: 1;
  line-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

On the other hand, this problem could be easily overcome using just one line of code of [CARTO VL](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/) [as explained in this example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-style-by-category):

```
color: ramp($name, vivid)
```

Link to the working example [here](https://cartodb.github.io/carto-vl/examples/editor/index.html#eyJhIjoid29ybGRfYm9yZGVycyIsImIiOiIiLCJjIjoicmFtaXJvY2FydG9kYiIsImQiOiJodHRwczovL3t1c2VyfS5jYXJ0by5jb20iLCJlIjoiY29sb3I6IHJhbXAoJG5hbWUsIHZpdmlkKVxuc3Ryb2tlV2lkdGg6IDAuM1xuIiwiZiI6eyJsbmciOi0zMC4yMTgxODgyODE0NzcxODIsImxhdCI6MjMuMTEzOTIzOTY5NDczODE3fSwiZyI6MS4zMDk0NzczNTE3NjQwMTEsImgiOiJWb3lhZ2VyIiwiaSI6ImRhdGFzZXQifQ==).

[image: carto-vl-viz]

What CARTO VL is doing behind the scenes is interpolating the colors when the 10 categories are reached.

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct idea that CartoCSS is something that would assist in this effort of yours. I believe the color ramp will generally work with about 7 or so colors before it lumps everything else in the "Other" category.

I would suggest referencing [Tips & Tricks - Geospatial Analysis](https://carto.com/docs/tips-and-tricks/geospatial-analysis/)

```
SELECT cartodb_id,
   the_geom,
   the_geom_webmercator,
   cartodb_id % 36 as modulus       
 FROM populated_places
```

Using the modulus, you can input your each of the fills as such

```
#layer {
marker-width: 3;
marker-fill-opacity: 2;
marker-allow-overlap: false;
marker-line-width: 1;

[modulus=0]{marker-fill: #73AF48;}
[modulus=1]{marker-fill: #CC503E;}
.
.
.
[modulus=36]{marker-fill: #0F8554;}    
}
```